# How do I change all references to a string in a class with css in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Hello I am trying to target all references to the phrase "Elementor" in each item that has the "post-state" class and then apply css changes to just those. I am not too savvy with JQuery or Javascript so any guidance would be greatly appreciated. This is the code I have concocted. It does not seem to be working.

```
var elementor = document.getElementsByClassName("post-state");

if($('elementor:contains("Elementor")')){
    elementor.style.color = 'red !important';
    elementor.style.fontWeight = 'bold !important';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like, should work:

```
// Target all the elements with 'post-state' css class containing "Elementor" string
$('.post-state:contains("Elementor")').each(function () {
  $(this).css("color", 'red !important');
  $(this).css("fontWeight", 'bold !important');
});
```

The selector `$('.post-state:contains("Elementor")')` will select all the elements with class `post-state` that contain the text string `Elementor`.

`.each()` will iterate all the elements in the selector and loop over each, with `this` as a reference to the individual element.